# Counting Occurrences of Zip Codes in Big Data Set w/Python

Tags: python, csv, counter, zipcode

I'm a python newbie looking to count the 100 most occurring zip codes in several .csv files (6+). There are literally 3 million+ zip codes in the data set, and I'm looking for a way to pull out only the top 100 most occurring. Here is a sample of code below that was inspired from another post, although I'm trying to count across several .csv files. Thanks in advance!

```
import csv
import collections

zip = collections.Counter()
with open('zipcodefile1.csv', 'zipcodefile2.csv', 'zipcodefile3.csv') as input file:
   for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';'):
       ZIP[row[1]] += 1

print ZIP.most_common(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Python's *generators* here, as they will be nice and efficient. First, suppose we have two files:

`zc1.txt`:

```
something;00001
another;00002
test;00003
```

and `zc2.txt`:

```
foo;00001
bar;00001
quuz;00003
```

Now let's write a function that takes several filenames and iterates through the lines in *all* of the files, returning only the zip codes:

```
import csv

def iter_zipcodes(paths):
    for path in paths:
        with open(path) as fh:
            for row in csv.reader(fh, delimiter=';'):
                yield row[1]
```

Note that we write `yield row[1]`. This signals that the function is a *generator*, and it returns its values lazily.

We can test it out as follows:

```
>>> list(iter_zipcodes(['zc1.txt', 'zc2.txt']))
['00001', '00002', '00003', '00001', '00001', '00003']
```

So we see that the generator simply spits out the zip codes in each file, in order. Now let's count them:

```
>>> zipcodes = iter_zipcodes(['zc1.txt', 'zc2.txt'])
>>> counts = collections.Counter(zipcodes)
>>> counts
Counter({'00001': 3, '00002': 1, '00003': 2})
```

Looks like it worked. This approach is efficient because it only reads one line in at a time. When one file is completely read, it moves on to the next.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response  jme! Your explanation was very clear and helped me understand what is going on under the hood.